# Virtual Host different port in wamp or xampp

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost

I am familiar with using virtual host with default port. Just now default port 80 was taken by another program. So, Would that be possible to create virtual host with custom port like 81 or 83 something like that.

Just now, I have to call phpmyadmin, using `http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin` but I can't create another project like http://test.local Below are the codes that I use in some files. Before I ask here, I google it, but no solution worked!

```
httpd-vhosts.conf file

NameVirtualHost *:81
  <VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\test"
    ServerName test.local
  <Directory "D:\wamp\www\test">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>



hosts file
127.0.0.1:81       car.local


httpd.conf file
Listen 81
```

So, How do I need to do to get http://test.local like that url. I have installed wamp and xampp in my computer.